# How does Armor of Earth work?

Tags: spells, l5r, l5r-2e

The spell Armor of earth pg. 216 in L5R 2ed Player's guide states:

> For the duration of the spell all damage dice rolled against a shugenja which are less than or equal to their caster's school rank are ignored.

So if the caster's school rank is 4, what does that mean?

a) The opponent gets to roll 5 dice and 4 are ignored.

b) Of the dice rolled by the opponent, any value of 4 or lower doesn't affect the caster.

c) Something else completely?

Answer (score 7):

b is the correct answer - if the enemy attacker hit, and then rolled 5k3 for damage, and the results were 1,2,3,8,12 (from an exploding ten), then they could only keep the 8 and 12 for a total of 20 damage - the rest are ignored. Without the spell effect, the damage would be 8+12+3 = 23. If, on the other hand, the attacker rolled all 4 or less, there would be no damage.

IIRC, this is the same mechanic as Armor/Carapace for Shadowlands creatures.

Comment: You mean the 1 & 2 *couldn't* be kept, which doesn't really change the example result?  (Side note: The Defense skill works similarly with the To Hit roll)

Comment: Woops - brain bad, better fix that...

Comment: And with that edit, my +1, Zuno.